# program that tells if a number is prime

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf, primes

you enter a number and the program will find if the number is prime or not
so when I enter the number 7 for the first time it will show you 'the number is prime'
then I enter 8 and it will show you 'the number is not prime'
after that I re_enter the number 7 and it will show you 'the number is not prime'
I don't know where is the problem 
please help me
[an example photo from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlp5q.png) 
and my code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void){
int n;
int t;
int isPrime=0;
char var;

while(var!='q'){
    printf("q=quit  p=prime  :");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c",&var);
    if(var=='p'){
        printf("plz put the number value :");
        scanf(" %d",&n);
        for(t=2;t<=n/2;t++){
            if (n%t==0){
                isPrime=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime==0){
            printf("%d is a prime number\n",n);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d is not a prime number\n",n);
        }
    }
    else if(var=='q'){
        printf("thank you bye\n");
        break;
    }
    else{
        printf("a wrong letter\n");
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `fflush (stdin)`

Comment: You asked this before. I know because you used the same *extremely bad* title... Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - and, whenever you got a minute, read the [tour].

Comment: @EdHeal: It's a Microsoft idiosyncrasy.

Comment: Thank you I guess some of my "stdin" tonight is going to be hot "stdout" considering the chillies in the supper

Comment: @EdHeal Don't forget to flush :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `isPrime` to `0` each time the user enters a number. Otherwise, it still holds the value from the previous number.

Move the variable declaration

```
int isPrime = 0;
```

inside the `while` loop.

BTW, isn't that variable name backwards? You set it to `1` (i.e. `true`) when you discover that there's a number that divides it equally. But that's when the number is **not** prime.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to reset isPrime back to zero inside the "while" loop.

By they way, looks like you are doing this as a learning exercise. That's good, there's no better way to learn than to try things out.

Here's a tip in C, any non-zero value is treated as "true", and zero is treated as "false".  So instead of this:

```
if (myFlag==1) { ... do something }
```

Just write this:

```
if (myFlag) { ... do something }
```